# Citric acid cycle original paper

Tags: organic-chemistry

According to wikipedia, it was published by Krebs&Johnson to the Enzymologia journal in 1937 [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Adolf_Krebs), "citric acid cycle" section]. However, I'm really struggling to find a digital copy. I thought maybe someone has come across it? It's a pity that there's no copy of a paper that won a Nobel prize.

Comment: It is reprinted [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0014579380805643)

Comment: Interesting to see "close votes" for a genuine research query and marking it as a homework question!  So much negativity. Enzymologia is not online but journal citation is here https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/19371405235. Many multilingual journals which published in French, German and English vanished with the passage of time. Such journals had Latin names to make them appear neutral. Some of them still do well like Talanta, Analytica Chimica Acta, Helvetica, Chromatographia. Older scientists often had a reading knowledge of German/French/Russian.

Comment: Awesooome, thanks @MaxW!

@M.Farooq I think for the research community as a whole it's good to have a common language, but there's definitely some nostalgic charm in having to learn a foreign language in order to read a publication of high interest:)

Comment: @M.Farooq - understand foreign languages?!? I think you expect too much from us poor Americans. We can't even speak real English. ;-)

Comment: @MaxW, Actually, I have just submitted a sequel to my previous article for people like you and me...how to best use machine translation for scientific purposes and my focus was French and German. The theme addresses exactly your concerns. Many fundamental articles or articles of historical interest remain in other non-English languages. I took help from native speakers.